# Executing shell script in different directory using PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec, ubuntu-server

I have a shell script in the `/home/` directory. I'd like to execute it by using a web page. The webserver is located in `/var/www/.` I'm wondering how would I execute the shell script from within the homepage using PHP?

I'm using Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [php exec function:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec('/path/to/shell/script');
```

However this will only work if safe_mode is disabled, php has permissions to such folder and file, or is defined in your basedir.